# Stuck in karma validation homework (nodejs, angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, karma-runner, mean-stack

I have a homework with the [MEAN Stack](http://mean.io/#!/) in which in need to change 2 files to pass a karma test. 
These two files are `search_bar.html` and function in `controller.js`.
The idea is to make the [test.js](https://paste.kde.org/pk5xzewba) file pass.

Sounds simple enough, but I can't for the love of my life do it. I read the assignment over and over again, and this is what I got to:

**search_bar.html:**

```
<div class="search-bar-wrapper">
    <input class="search-bar-input" ng-model="searchText" ng-change="update()"/>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="product in productsList" class="autocomplete-result">
    {{product}}
</div>
```

**Controller.js:**

```
exports.SearchBarController = function($scope, $http) {
    // TODO: this function should make an HTTP request to
    // `/api/v1/product/text/:searchText` and expose the response's
    // `products` property as `results` to the scope.
    $scope.update = function() {
        $http.
            get('/api/v1/product/text/' + $scope.searchText).
                success(function(data) {
                    $scope.productsList = data;
                }
            );
    };
```

The goal of the homework is as follows:

> - You will have to modify SearchBarController in controllers.js to fill out the update() function, which will make an HTTP request to the
>     server and expose the server's response to your HTML.
> - You will have to modify the HTML in templates/search_bar.html to add an input field with class 'search-bar-input' that has a two-way
>     data binding to the searchText variable, and calls the update()
>     function using the ngChange directive. You will also need to ngRepeat
>     a div element with class 'autocomplete-result' for each search result.

I believe my current code does just that, but apparently it is wrong. I have been stuck in here for a long time now and I can't see what is wrong.

Can someone help?

===============================================================

**Additional Info:**

If you are curious or are feeling like doing the good deed of the day (I hope to God you do), here is additional information about the homework, as well as a [zip file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-UP5lxiQ9AodEotYjhIanlMUE0/view) with it:

> In this exercise, you will implement the home view for the MEAN retail
>   application, the first view that the user will see when they visit
>   your site. The view contains a single search bar that searches for
>   products by text, that is, using the/api/v1/product/text/:query REST
>   API endpoint.
>
> You will primarily be concerned with writing code that passes the
>   mocha tests specified in the test.js file. You will notneed to
>   actually run your code in the browser, you will instead use gulp and
>   karma to run your tests. The tests intest.js will provide you faster
>   feedback, and also will provide you an exact specification for what
>   you need to do to complete this exercise.
>
> In order to run tests, you should:
>
> - Run npm install in the provided sample code
> - Start gulp using ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp watch
> - Start karma using ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start ./karma.local.conf.js
> - You should take a look at the tests in test.js to see exactly what your AngularJS code should do.
> - Modify controllers.js and templates/search_bar.html as described below until the tests pass and karma gives you the below output:
>
>   LOG: 'Tests Succeeded! Copy/paste the below code to complete this assignment:'
>     LOG: ''
>     Chrome 43.0.2357 (Linux): Executed 4 of 4 SUCCESS (0.21 secs / 0.126 secs)

Comment: If you want help to fix the failing test(s) you should also show the test(s) :)

Comment: The test file is kinda big, I will find a way to post it soon!

Comment: Added a link to the test.js file. If some one has ideas, I am all ears !

Comment: "but apparently it is wrong" --- how do you know that?

Comment: My code fails some tests 

Comment: Exactly what tests are failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the answer provided by HankScorpio guided me into the right direction, it was not complete and left some things for explanation.

The one thing that really helped me (since I am new at this) was to carefully check the tests themselves with karma, in specific this one:

```
it('makes an HTTP request to `/api/v1/product/text/test` and exposes results to scope', function(done) {
    httpBackend.expectGET('/api/v1/product/text/test').respond({
      products: [{ name: 'test1' }, { name: 'test2' }]
    });

    scope.$on('SearchBarController', function() {
      element.find('input').val('test');
      element.find('input').trigger('input');
      assert.equal(scope.searchText, 'test');

      httpBackend.flush();
      assert.equal(scope.results.length, 2);
      assert.equal(scope.results[0].name, 'test1');
      assert.equal(scope.results[1].name, 'test2');

      ++succeeded;
      done();
    });
  });
```

Here I can see that in deed I need a `scope.results` and `product.name` variables and also that in the controller I should have `data.products`.

As suspected, I was close, but the names of the variables were throwing me off. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

> 1. "makes an HTTP request to `/api/v1/product/text/test` and exposes results to scope"

`$scope.productsList = data;` should be `$scope.results = data;` (be sure to read the question, your instructor or whoever wrote that TODO comment told you to name it `results`, not `productsList`), and of course anywhere else you're referencing `productsList` should be changed to `results` too.

> 2. "displays autocomplete results in HTML"

`{{product}}` should be `{{product.name}}`

Comment: Close, but no cigar! Still, your efforts guided me. The bounty is yours, as deserved!